# locales broken on Beaglebone Black running Debian

Tags: linux, debian, locale, arm, beaglebone

So this all started when I wanted to install my custom daemon on my Beaglebone Black running Debian using `update-rc.d mydaemon defaults 97` like I've done many times during it's development on my Mint host. And I'm greeted with:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
   LANGUAGE = (unset),
   LC_ALL = (unset),
   LC_PAPER = "es_CL.UTF-8",
   LC_ADDRESS = "es_CL.UTF-8",
   LC_MONETARY = "es_CL.UTF-8",
   LC_NUMERIC = "es_CL.UTF-8",
   LC_TELEPHONE = "es_CL.UTF-8",
   LC_IDENTIFICATION = "es_CL.UTF-8",
   LC_MEASUREMENT = "es_CL.UTF-8",
   LC_NAME = "es_CL.UTF-8",
   LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
```

Which I subsequently tried to fix with `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, to which it replies

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
     are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.ISO-8859-1...locale alias file `/usr/share/locale/locale.alias' not found: No such file or directory
 done
Generation complete.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_MONETARY = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LANG = "C"
     are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_MONETARY = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "es_CL.UTF-8",
    LANG = "C"
     are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I have no idea how to fix this as it refuses to let me install any packages or update anything...
Anyone have any ideas? I'm stumped...

p.s. I've seen [Configure Locales on Debian](https://superuser.com/questions/833530/configure-locales-on-debian) and this does not work for me (i.e. `source /etc/default/locale`)

p.p.s I also checked `/etc/locales.gen` shell and `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` is uncommented as it is supposed to be and the shell script suggests to run `locale-gen` and I get

```
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
en_US.UTF-8...locale alias file `/usr/share/locale/locale.alias' not found: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after looking through all the Debian manuals and the BeagleBone build I finally figured out what has happened! I thought I'd put this up in case anyone runs into this problem. In order to fix the locales I needed to manually re-write the `/etc/default/locale` file with: (if your in north American for example you would use "en_US.UTF-8" for all).

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_CL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_CL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_CL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_CL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_CL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_CL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_CL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_CL.UTF-8"
```

You then need to ensure the shell script `/etc/locale.gen` has all the locales you intend to use uncommented i.e. `sudo nano /etc/locale.gen`.

You then need to fix the symbolic link that locales expects, that the kernel should have made on installation, this is done by: `sudo ln -s /etc/locale.alias /usr/share/locale/locale.alias`

Finally run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to fix the linking, and everything should be running fine now.

(On a side note: I realized later that the `update-rc.d` is a legacy tool on the later Debian releases, such as that on the BeagleBone black, the daemon shell should be installed using `insserv mydaemon` instead)

Comment: This worked on a debian container build. Thanks!