# How to fix locale settings in Debian 7?

Tags: debian, locale

I'm having massive problems with Debian's locale Settings.

I want my server to talk to me in standard English `(en_US.UTF-8?)` and additionally have `de_DE.UTF-8` available for a few Python scripts that require it. I fudged around with pretty much all combinations of `locale-gen`, `dpkg-reconfigure` locales and editing of config files.

Now, when logging into my server, I'm greeted with this:

```
Last login: Fri Mar 13 22:23:14 2015 from 1.2.3.4
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (de_DE.UTF-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (de_DE.UTF-8)
```

What does this *even mean*?

On my other server, I somehow managed to configure everything correctly, and `locale -a` correctly outputs the following there:

```
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

On this server, however, I only get this at the moment:

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure Locales on Debian](https://superuser.com/questions/833530/configure-locales-on-debian)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that `locale-gen` refused to generate a de_DE locale because it was commented out in `/etc/locale.gen`.

[image: locale.gen]

As you can see here, I've uncommented the locales I want. After a quick `locale-gen`, everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

The way I adjust this on Ubuntu is to open the `locale` file like this; using `nano` in this example but feel free to use whatever editor you prefer:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/locale
```

And then add—or edit—the `LANG` value like this:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

More info & details can be found in this answer on [“Ask Ubuntu.”](https://askubuntu.com/a/454302)

Comment: That fixed the warnings on login, but I still need the `de_DE` locale.